# Scaling in CircuiTikZ

Tags: scaling, circuitikz

When scaling a circuit with the scale option:
`\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 'some_scale_factor']`
all the *coordinates* are well scaled but **not the components**.

How to correctly scale the whole scheme?

Comment: It could be done with the "transform shape" option. =)

Comment: Or wrap the whole thing in a `\scalebox{<factor>}{..}` (`graphicx` package) or `\begin{adjustbox}{scale=<factor>}` .. `\end{adjustbox}` (`adjustbox` pacakge). There should be a similar question about TikZ itself around.

Comment: Related question (as @MartinScharrer hinted): [How to scale Tikz drawings and text together?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18228/how-to-scale-tikz-drawings-and-text-together)

Comment: @Martin: this will affect the font size. Is there a way to scale everything but the font?

Comment: @pluton:
I don't know if there's a way to do not scale the font, but you can rescale it with `\scalefont`: 

`{\scalefont{scale_factor} text_or_tikz_code}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just to summarize:

My answer:

> It could be done with the "transform shape" option: `\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 'some_scale_factor', transform shape]`

Martin's answer:

> Wrap the whole thing in a `\scalebox{<factor>}{..} (graphicx package)` or `\begin{adjustbox}{scale=<factor>} .. \end{adjustbox} (adjustbox pacakge)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to scale only the components but not the text, you can use `/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length` (taken from [Scaling components in CircuiTikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32156/scaling-components-in-circuitikz/32169)):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
    to [sV=$a_1$] (2,0)
    to [C=$\SI{100}{\ohm}$](3,0)
    to [sV=$a_2$] (5,0)
    to [sV=$a_1$] (7,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{circuitikz}[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm]
\draw (0,0)
    to [sV=$a_1$] (2,0)
    to [C=$\SI{100}{\ohm}$](3,0)
    to [sV=$a_2$] (5,0)
    to [sV=$a_1$] (7,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Note that you can combine this with `scale`, `xscale`, or `yscale` to scale the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Just Providing an example of Leonardos example (The diagram is scaled):
[image]

```
            \documentclass[11 pt]{article}

            \usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
            \usepackage{adjustbox}

            \begin{document}
            \begin{center}
            \textbf{Induction Motor}
            \\
            \begin{adjustbox}{scale=0.6}
            \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.4]
            \def\topy{2.5}
            \def\boty{0}
            \def\midx{3}
            \def\halfmidx{1.5}
            \def\farx{6}
            \def\halffarx{4.5}

            \draw(0,\topy) 
            to[open,v_=$V_\phi$,o-o] (0,\boty)
            to[short] (\midx,\boty)
            to[L=$j X_m$] (\midx,\topy)
            ;
            \draw (0,\topy)
            to[R=$R_1$] (\halfmidx,\topy)
            to[L=$j X_1$] (\midx,\topy)
            ;

            \draw(\midx,\topy)
            to[R=$R_2 $] (\halffarx , \topy)
            to[L=$j X_2$] (\farx , \topy)
            to[R=$R_2\frac{1-s}{s}$] (\farx,\boty)
            to[short] (\midx , \boty)
            ;

            \end{circuitikz}
            \end{adjustbox}
            \end{center}

            \end{document}
```

Comment: (1) some explanation should be add, at least what is the point of your answer,  (2) essential your answer is equal to the comment of Martin Scharrer (from September 2011) .