# Changing the size of a Logic Gate using Circuitikz

Tags: graphics, circuitikz, size

I would like to change the size of a simple logic gate

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) node[and port] () {};
\end{circuitikz}
```

The output is:

[image]

How can I control the size of the ouptut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! As usual in this kind of business with `scale=<factor>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[and port,scale=3] (n) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the height and width of `circuitikz` components locally or globally using `\ctikzset`.
(Inspired from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288276/28557))

#### Doing it locally

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) node[and port] () {};
\draw
\pgfextra{\ctikzset{tripoles/american and port/width=.55,
                        tripoles/american and port/height=.4}}
(0,-1.5) node[and port] () {};
\draw
\pgfextra{\ctikzset{tripoles/american and port/width=.3,
                        tripoles/american and port/height=.2}}
(0,-2.5) node[and port] () {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Doing it globally

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\ctikzset{tripoles/american and port/width=.55,tripoles/american and port/height=.4}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[and port] () {};
\draw (0,-1) node[or port](){};
\draw (0,-2) node[and port] () {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]