# Circutikz how to scale down a single 'bipole' in a diagram

Tags: circuitikz

I am not entirely satisfied with the relative size of Operational Amplifier and (american) resistor in this simple circuit:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw
(0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
(opamp.+) node[ground] {}
(opamp.-) to [short, *-o] ++(-0.3,0) node[left] (a) {$i_i$}
(opamp.out) node[right] {$v_o$}
(opamp.out) --++(0,0.6) to[R] ++(-1,0) -| (opamp.-)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: OpAmp_1]

I thought the easiest way is to scale the resistor down, by changing the line to:

```
(opamp.out) --++(0,0.6) to[R,scale=0.8] ++(-1,0) -| (opamp.-)
```

However, what I get is this:

[image: OpAmp_2]

No matter how I tried (curly braces around the `to` operation, using a `node` instead), I could not get the desired effect for the `bipole` (term which, btw, is not really used in English to define one-ports, at least so tells me Google).

I resorted to scaling **the rest** of the elements up, because for `nodes` the procedure is no issue.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw
(0,0) node[op amp,scale=1.4] (opamp) {}
(opamp.+) node[ground] {}
(opamp.-) to [short, *-o] ++(-0.3,0) node[left] (a) {$i_i$}
(opamp.out) node[right] {$v_o$}
(opamp.out) --++(0,1) --++(-0.35,0) to[R] ++(-1,0) -| (opamp.-)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: OpAmp_3]

However, I would like to know whether there is a proper way to scale the 'non-nodes' in `circutikz` and what the correct syntax would then be.

Comment: Maybe help and possibly duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32169/31034

Answer (score 1):

The following properties are defined for `op amp`.

```
\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/width/.initial=1.7}
\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/port width/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/height/.initial=1.4}
\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/input height/.initial=.5}
\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/up pos/.initial=.45}
\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/font/.initial= \fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\boldmath}%absolut font size needed!
```

Checkout [this file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/tex/pgfcirc.defines.tex) for more such options for other shapes.