# Circuitkz arrowhead scaling

Tags: arrows, circuitikz

I have problem with scaling of the arrowhead (see figure below). I found some examples, but unfortunately it does not work: [question 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf/80090#80090), [question 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-make-an-arrow-bigger-and-change-its-color-in-tikz), [question 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29270/scaling-in-circuitikz). I would like to reduce arrowhead of the current (for better proportion with arrows of the voltage).

[image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{circuitikz}  
  \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
  \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \usepackage{subfig} 

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \subfloat[ ]   {
        \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
          \draw (0,0) node[ocirc] {} --+ (1,0) coordinate(A); 
          \coordinate (B) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]A);
          \draw (A) to[R] (B) --+ (-1,0) coordinate(D) node[ocirc] {}; 

          \begin{scope}[shorten >= 10pt,shorten <= 10pt]

            \draw[arrows={-open triangle 45}]
               ([xshift=.6cm,yshift=-0.5cm]A) -- node[right] {$i(t)$} ([xshift=.6cm,yshift=0.5cm]B); 
            \draw[->]  (0,0) -- node[left] {$u(t)$} (D);            
          \end{scope}         
        \end{circuitikz}    
    }
    \subfloat[ ]   {
        \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
          \draw (0,0) node[ocirc] {} --+ (1,0) coordinate(A); 
          \coordinate (B) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]A);
          \draw (A) to[L] (B) --+ (-1,0) coordinate(D) node[ocirc] {}; 

          \begin{scope}[shorten >= 10pt,shorten <= 10pt]
            \draw[arrows={-open triangle 45}]  ([xshift=.6cm,yshift=-0.5cm]A) -- node[right] {$i(t)$} ([xshift=.6cm,yshift=0.5cm]B); 
            \draw[->]  (0,0) -- node[left] {$u(t)$} (D);
          \end{scope}         
        \end{circuitikz}
    }   
  \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`arrows.new`](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/_discuss/thread/d0a57d64/095c/attachment/tikzlibraryarrows.new.code.tex) tikz library, and `-open triangle 45 new,arrow head=3pt` you can get what you want (change `3pt` to the desired length):

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{circuitikz}  
  \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.new}
  \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \usepackage{subfig} 

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \subfloat[ ]   {
        \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
          \draw (0,0) node[ocirc] {} --+ (1,0) coordinate(A); 
          \coordinate (B) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]A);
          \draw (A) to[R] (B) --+ (-1,0) coordinate(D) node[ocirc] {}; 

          \begin{scope}[shorten >= 10pt,shorten <= 10pt]

            \draw[-open triangle 45 new,arrow head=3pt]
               ([xshift=.6cm,yshift=-0.5cm]A) -- node[right] {$i(t)$} ([xshift=.6cm,yshift=0.5cm]B); 
            \draw[->]  (0,0) -- node[left] {$u(t)$} (D);            
          \end{scope}         
        \end{circuitikz}    
    }
    \subfloat[ ]   {
        \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
          \draw (0,0) node[ocirc] {} --+ (1,0) coordinate(A); 
          \coordinate (B) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]A);
          \draw (A) to[L] (B) --+ (-1,0) coordinate(D) node[ocirc] {}; 

          \begin{scope}[shorten >= 10pt,shorten <= 10pt]
            \draw[-open triangle 45 new,arrow head=3pt]  ([xshift=.6cm,yshift=-0.5cm]A) -- node[right] {$i(t)$} ([xshift=.6cm,yshift=0.5cm]B); 
            \draw[->]  (0,0) -- node[left] {$u(t)$} (D);
          \end{scope}         
        \end{circuitikz}
    }   
  \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Download the file `tikzlibraryarrows.new.code.tex` and save it somewhere TeX can find it (the current working directory, for a quick run).

Comment: Why this library is not included in Miktex sw?

Comment: @jafan this library was developed by user Luigi from his answer to one of the questions you linked to. The library is still not part of PGF. You might have to ask the author why is this so.

Answer (score 3):

On the search for scaling an `open triangle 45` I found a different option that I assume was introduced with TikZ 3.0:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define a new style for the arrow tip
    \tikzset{myArrowStyle/.style={arrows = {{Stealth[inset=0pt,scale=5,fill=white,angle'=45]}-}}}
    % Draw arrow
    \draw[myArrowStyle] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
Some text as reference regarding the size...
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]