# Scalable node shape size

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, scaling

I can adjust the shape of nodes using commands such as `minimum width` or `inner xsep`, but these require explicit units. When I scale the entire figure (`\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.5]`) it does not scale the node.

**NOTE** The following question does not solve my problem:
[Using scalable sizes for rectangles, circles and nodes in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29656/using-scalable-sizes-for-rectangles-circles-and-nodes-in-tikz)

Because when I add arrows from the node they do not recognize the shapes that I drew around the node.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1]

\draw (0,0) circle (1.5) node (A) {A};
\draw (0,4) circle (1.5) node (B) {B};
\draw [->] (A) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end {document}
```

Comment: Node scaling needs `transform shape` in the picture options for all nodes or in the node options for individual selection. So that question doesn't but the linked one in that question solves your problem; http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29662/what-are-the-guidelines-for-making-tikz-pictures-properly-scalable