# Draw a figure (cut-off functions) in tikz

Tags: tikz-styles, code, draw

Please I need the code tikz for this figure.

I have this code but it's not correct :

```
[![\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}\[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm\]
\draw\[thick\] plot\[domain=-100:40,samples=100\] ({3.5*cos(\x)},{1.5*sin(\x)+.3*cos(2*\x)}) node {$Q$};
\foreach \x/\i in {-40/j,-70/i} {
\draw\[thick\] ({2.5*cos(\x)},{1*sin(\x)+.15*cos(2.2*\x)}) circle(.4);
\draw\[thick,dotted\] ({2.5*cos(\x)},{1*sin(\x)+.15*cos(2.2*\x)}) circle(.5);
\draw ({2.5*cos(\x)},{1*sin(\x)+.15*cos(2.2*\x)}) node {$\varphi_{\delta}^{\pm}$};
\draw ({2.5*cos(\x)},{1*sin(\x)+.15*cos(2.2*\x)})++(-.37,.6) node {$U_{\delta}^{\pm}$};
\draw ({2.5*cos(\x)},{1*sin(\x)+.15*cos(2.2*\x)})++(-.1,.2) node {$K_{\delta}^{\pm}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The contruction of cut-off functions}\label{Fig4}
\end{figure}][1]][1]
```

[image: Figure]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use nodes together with the fitting library, it does much of the work for you:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6] %this scales the whole image

\node[circle,draw] (+) {$\begin{gathered}k_\delta^+\\\varphi_S^+\end{gathered}$};
\node[fit=(+),draw,dashed,circle,label=above left:$U_S^+$] (U+) {};

\node[circle,draw,right=50pt of +] (-) {$\begin{gathered}k_\delta^-\\\varphi_S^-\end{gathered}$};
\node[fit=(-),draw,dashed,circle,label=above right:$U_S^+$](U-){};

\node[fit=(U+) (U-),ellipse,draw,inner sep=15pt,label=above right:$\varphi$]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

Concerning your question in the comments: the scale option will scale most things **but not all**. Many parameters in nodes will not be affected. If you really want to scale everything (including text) you should use the `transform canvas` option. You will find the relevant information in section 25.4 of the current tikz manual or you can take a look at an answer I gave to another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18231/3708).

Another way to make the diagram smaller is to reduce the dimensions such as the minimum size of the nodes, the inner and outer separations of the nodes as well as text size.

Comment: Thank you
Please I need to reduce the size of the figure.

Comment: The simplest way to reduce a complete tikz image is to include the scale option: \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6] .